# Is there is a built-in way to filter out connected nodes in friends of friend type query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say we have a social network, and one wants to find friends of friends that one is not currently connected to.  I assume that we could do something like:

```
match (me)-[:Friends_With]-(other)-[:Friends_With]-(target)
where not (target-[:Friends_With]-me)
return target
```

From what I can tell, Neo will not include `me` in `target`, but it will include nodes that currently connect to me via `[:Friends_with]`. Assuming that my first query works, is there a less verbose way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (me:Person { name: "Kenny" })-[:FRIEND_OF]-()-[:FRIEND_OF]-(foaf:Person)
WHERE NOT (me)-[:FRIEND_OF]-(foaf)
RETURN foaf
```

This is the least verbose yet most expressive query for finding a friend of a friend that I am not friends with.